# The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, checkout

I'm trying this code but it returned me this error.I think issue with clientID i changed the clientID with other account then it work fine but when i tried to implement this clientID which is in the code ,it's show me error.
Anyone who can help me in this regard.I will be very thankful to you.

```
<head>
  <title>Paypal Checkout</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Ensures optimal rendering on mobile devices. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!-- Optimal Internet Explorer compatibility -->
</head>

<body>
  <script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Ae5Nri4XLfck8VR95yNNjYo8UymUe4n7Uk3DBID2UlkpemxB125veepMUkM5DxEiglownCaxa3jb1KR5">
  </script>

    enter code here

  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '10'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        console.log(details);
      });
    }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: As this is more of a business issues (the particular account is the problem and not the code) then I've voted to close as not reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clientID that i'm using this account is restricted.When i open the inspect the code then i got this message
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZWB.png)